# findall не выдает результат по маске

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Пробую спарсить страницы с сайта. Маска вроде правильная, но из-за того что то что надо спрарсить находятся еще теги возможно не понимает что искать. Мне нужно то что находиться от `<div class="article-section__content en main"` до первого `</div>`. Результат пустой список. Вот код:

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import re

link_now = 'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781119183518.ch5'
response = requests.get(link_now, headers={'User_Agent': UserAgent().chrome})
html = response.text#.content

obj1 = re.findall('on__content en main">(.*?)</div>', html)

print(type(obj1))

print (obj1)`
```

> ```
> <class 'list'> 
> []
> ```

Comment: Точка в регулярке не захватывает переносы строк по умолчанию; `re.findall(... , flags=re.DOTALL)` но конечно лучше делать как MaxU в ответе написал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше парсить HTML используя [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    #  pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

res = soup.find('div', {'class': 'article-section__content en main'}).text

print(res)
```

результат:

```
This chapter focuses on MapReduce, a model of parallel computation that enables to structure problems, so as to harness hundreds or even thousands of
 computers to process data faster than it accumulates. It introduces algorithms to carry out computations with fewer resources than one would see fro
m traditional approaches, while delivering approximations to the expected results within guaranteed bounds. MapReduce is named for two functions from
 the functional programming literature: map and reduce. These functions represent the purely parallel and sequential parts of a computation. The Hype
rLogLog (HLL) is a probabilistic data structure for estimating the number of distinct elements in a set, known as the set's cardinality. The effectiv
eness of HLL makes this algorithm a first‐class citizen in modern analytics. A Count‐Min Sketch (CMS) is a probabilistic data structure used to repre
sent frequency tables. The CMS is simple to implement and has an immense use in serving a certain class of frequency queries.
```

Comment: а как сделать это регулярными через findall?

Comment: @Павел а зачем?

Comment: bf тормозит весь процесс, если надо много скачивать

Comment: выдает ошибку AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_xml'

Answer (score 1):

Такое решение будет работать, но только на самом деле проще парсить конечно через BS.

```
re.findall('on__content en main">(.*?)</div>', test_str, re.DOTALL)
```

результат:

> ```
> on__content en main">
> ```

> ```
> <p>This chapter focuses on MapReduce, a model of parallel computation that enables to structure problems, so as to harness hundreds or even thousands of computers to process data faster than it accumulates. It introduces algorithms to carry out computations with fewer resources than one would see from traditional approaches, while delivering approximations to the expected results within guaranteed bounds. MapReduce is named for two functions from the functional programming literature: map and reduce. These functions represent the purely parallel and sequential parts of a computation. The HyperLogLog (HLL) is a probabilistic data structure for estimating the number of distinct elements in a set, known as the set's cardinality. The effectiveness of HLL makes this algorithm a first‐class citizen in modern analytics. A Count‐Min Sketch (CMS) is a probabilistic data structure used to represent frequency tables. The CMS is simple to implement and has an immense use in serving a certain class of frequency queries.</p>
> ```

> ```
> </div>
> ```