# Не понимаю, почему регулярка не работает

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

```
import re

string = """<div class="src ltr">
        <span class="text">
          Minors received mandatory legal representation, including court-appointed lawyers for those whose families could not <em>afford</em> representation.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="trg ltr">
        <span class="icon jump-right"></span>
        <span class="text" lang='ru'>
          Несовершеннолетним в обязательном порядке обеспечивается участие в судебном процессе их законных представителей, в том числе назначаемых судом адвокатов для тех, чьи семьи не могут <a class="link_highlighted" href='/translation/russian-english/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5' rel="nofollow"><em>позволить себе</em></a> такого представительства.</span>
      </div>
      """
pattern = r'''<div class="trg ltr">(\s)|(.*)\s+</div>''' 
regex = re.compile(pattern)
function_match = regex.findall(string)
print(function_match)
```

Написал регулярку, ошибок хоть убейте не вижу,мне нужно достать все между  `<div class="trg ltr">     </div>`. Ну конкретно предложение на русском языке, заключенное в блок.
А вот что я получаю в результате и не понимаю, в чем косяк моей регулярки:

**
[('', '          **Minors received mandatory legal representation, including court-appointed lawyers for those whose families could not *afford* representation.**'), ('\n', ''), ('', '          Несовершеннолетним в обязательном порядке обеспечивается участие в судебном процессе их законных представителей, в том числе назначаемых судом адвокатов для тех, чьи семьи не могут <a class="link_highlighted" href='/translation/russian-english/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5' rel="nofollow">*позволить себе* такого представительства.')]
**

Т.е каким-то образом он в моем регулярном выражении распознал:

```
<div class="src ltr">
        <span class="text">
          Minors received mandatory legal representation, including court-appointed lawyers for those whose families could not <em>afford</em> representation.</span>
      </div>
```

Когда не должен был!
Объясните, в чем косяк моей регулярки и почему она находит не только то что мне нужно, но и то, что мне ненужно. Как исправить ?

Comment: Это учебная задача или нет? Если нет, то не используйте регулярки для парсинга веб-документ — это никогда к ничему хорошему не приводит.

Comment: Так он находится все что между, в чем косяк? :) Вы сами такую регулярку написали.

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов так строка должна быть между <div class="trg ltr"> и <div>, а он нашел между <div class="src ltr"> </div>

Comment: Вы вообще что-то странное понаписали, можно ведь гораздо проще `regex = re.compile(r'<div class="trg ltr">(.*?)</div>', flags=re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Но в любом случае парсить html регулярками — заведомо хреновая идея

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов Задача учебная и не очень понял совета никогда не использовать регулярки для парсинга веб документов, а что использовать? В исходном коде beautifulsoup используются регулярки

Comment: @АндрейПетров beautifulsoup использует регулярки для совершенно отдельных вспомогательных задач, а не для непосредственно парсинга

Comment: @andreymal Ваш вариант сработал, но все же интересно, с чем связано, что регулярками веб документы не парсят?

Comment: Потому что документ может быть с ошибками, он может меняться, и еще кучу всяких проблем.

Comment: регулярки это writeonly код, который не расширить потом сильно при желании, как я и сказал, проблем очень и очень много

Comment: Все говорят, что использовать регулярки для разбора HTML плохо, но никто не может сказать, почему :) Если коротко, то регулярные выражения описывают регулярные языки. HTML является контекстно-свободным языком. Регулярные языки являются подмножеством контекстно-свободных. Т.е., это как узкоспециализированным инструментом пытаться решить широкую задачу. Подробнее можно почитать на [Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/171667/).

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [findall не выдает результат по маске](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/884192/findall-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score -1):

В тех случаях, когда мы хотим распарсить регулярным выражением что-то между конкретными символами, то будет проще ограничить множество символов по правой границе. Например, чтобы найти в URL все протоколы перед `://`, следует искать совпадения по такому множеству: `[^:]+?`. Здесь всё аналогично:

```
    regex = re.compile(r'<div class="trg ltr">([^<]*?)</div>')
```